# How to select the rows having same id and have all missing value in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  col_1
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    4.0
2    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
3    3.0
1    NaN
```

I need the following output:

```
ID  col_1
1    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
2    NaN
2    NaN
```

how to do this in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try with `isin` after `groupby` with `all`

```
s = df['col_1'].isna().groupby(df['ID']).all()
df = df.loc[df.ID.isin(s[s].index.tolist())]
df
Out[73]: 
   ID  col_1
0   1    NaN
1   2    NaN
3   2    NaN
4   2    NaN
7   1    NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a boolean mask with `isna` then group this mask by `ID` and `transform` using `all`, then you can filter the rows with the help of this mask:

```
mask = df['col_1'].isna().groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')
df[mask].sort_values('ID')
```

Alternatively you can use `groupby` + `filter` to filter out the groups which satisfy the condition where all values in `col_1` are `NaN` but this method should be slower than the above:

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: g['col_1'].isna().all()).sort_values('ID')
```

---

```
   ID  col_1
0   1    NaN
7   1    NaN
1   2    NaN
3   2    NaN
4   2    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel(r"D:\Stack_overflow\test12.xlsx")

df1=(df[df['cols_1'].isnull()]).sort_values(by=['ID'])
```

I think we can simply take out the null values.

Comment: this doesnot check if all values in the group is nan. Also you can use [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) to read data directly without having to write it to a file and read them :)